# Query a specific document inside 2 streamBuilder

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I created 2 different collections (users and follow).

Now I want to:

1. Fetch document which exist inside the follow's `collection("list")` according by their id.
2. Fetch users data in the first collection where `currentUid = doc.id` (for the second collection).
3. Display data in the `ListTile`.

##### First collection

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(currentUid).set({"name":username,"photoUrl":url,"uid":currentUid});
```

##### Second collection

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("follow").doc(currentUid).collection("list").doc(otherId);
```

I used this but it doesn't work properly

```dart
     body:StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
              stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection("follow")
              .doc(user!.uid)
              .collection("list")
              .snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot1) {
            if (!snapshot1.hasData) {
              return Container();
            } else {
              return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                    .collection("users")
                    .where("uid",
                        isEqualTo:
                            snapshot1.data!.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList())
                    .snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot2) {
                  if (!snapshot2.hasData) {
                    return Container();
                  } else {
                    return ListView(
                      children: snapshot2.data!.docs.map((e) {
                        return ListTile(
                          leading: CircleAvatar(
                            backgroundImage: NetworkImage(e.get('url')),
                            radius: 30,
                          ),
                          title: Text(e.get('username')),
                        );
                      }).toList(),
                    );
                  }
                },
              );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [in query](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_and_array-contains-any) instead of the `equal to` query.

> An in query returns documents where the given field matches any of the
> comparison values.

The syntax for the `in` query in the [cloud_firestore](https://pub.dev/packages/cloud_firestore) is this:

```dart
 .where(field, whereIn: listOfFields)
```

**Solution:**

Change this:

```dart
 .where("uid", isEqualTo: snapshot1.data!.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList())
```

to this:

```dart
 .where("uid", whereIn: snapshot1.data!.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList())
```